# $http.post posts null parameter to mvc.net api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this on my js

```
var modelo = {
    Estatus: 2,
    IdVet: 1                   
};

$http.post('/AdminV2/Vet/ActualizarEstatus', modelo)
    .then(function (res) {

    });
```

And this on my .cs

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ActualizarEstatus(ActualizarEstatus estatus)
{
    if (estatus == null)
    {
        return JsonResultBool(false);
    }
    return JsonResultBool(true);
}

public class ActualizarEstatus
{
    public int Estatus { get; set; }
    public int IdVet { get; set; }
}
```

And the parameter "estatus" is always null. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Corrected the example

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `ObtenerVets` instead `ActualizarEstatus`?

Comment: Do you need the [FromBody] attribute? So it'd be like
public JsonResult ActualizarEstatus([FromBody]ActualizarEstatus estatus)

Also, make sure you do what the other guy said and Json.stringify the object before you send it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things -

1. Make sure your `url` is right. I see your action method name as - `ActualizarEstatus`, but you are calling `/AdminV2/Vet/ObtenerVets` in your ajax call. That is not right, so correct it.
2. You have to use `estatus` variable name to pass data through ajax.

Please use following code, I tested it -

```
var modelo = {
    Estatus: 2,
    IdVet: 1
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/ActualizarEstatus", // this is my local url, change it with your valid url.
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ estatus: modelo }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

When i use above code, I get following output -

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I Ecapsuled modelo in { estatus: modelo } and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In your JS side make sure that you wrap your result in a Property called `estatus` before assigning to `var modelo`(the same name should be used in both C# and JS). Also `Stringify` this property before sending in `$http.post`

Answer (score 1):

You have to stringify your model. This wrapper helps your model to make json.

```
$http.post('/AdminV2/Vet/ObtenerVets', JSON.stringify(modelo))
.then(function (res) {

});
```